# 12.04, acer, actiontek

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, acer

My home wireless router will not accept any password and let me connect.  It goes to the connect screen and will continually reject my password.  I tested the password on another device to make sure it worked, I have copied and pasted it and typed it in visible plain text multiple times to see if it works.

My computer works on the wireless router in the local coffee shop.

Specs: Computer is an Acer aspire v3-571g-6407, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit

Router: http://www.actiontec.com/products/cat_desc.php?fid=42

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @braiam why do you think that will work if other devices can connect to said router?

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.